# Using X11 on OpenSUSE with WSL2

Tags: x11, kde, opensuse, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL2 on my computer, and with it I grabbed OpenSUSE so I could get some experience with a distro besides Ubuntu.

I sideloaded OpenSUSE 15.1, and it installed fine and loads into the terminal fine.

Now, in order to use things that have a GUI [I'm trying to get KDE], I need some sort of X11 window manager. I'm using Xming, which is probably the most popular one.
When I set the `$DISPLAY` variable with
`export DISPLAY=0.0`, it runs fine, and using `echo $DISPLAY` returns the same thing that I inputted.

However, when I run `startkde`, I get the following: `$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.`.
What might be causing this issue, and how might I get around it?

Comment: I have added an answer. If you want more then you will have to show us what you did: add a transcript of what you typed, and of the results.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: Install all of the needed X packages, and all of the KDE packages from YAST2.

Then, run this command:

```
export DISPLAY=<your.ip.goes.here>:0
```

That should do it.

Comment: You should not need the IP address, and there may be undesired effects of using it. There was a type in the original, that was fixed when you switched to IP form.

Answer (score 0):

The correct value is `export DISPLAY=":0"`. If you set it as you did, then you will get `Error: Can't open display: 0.0`. There is no need to use the IP address. This may affect performance, and have other undesired affects.